# Haskell -- could not deduce (a ~ Integer) in infinite sequence

Tags: haskell

```
powers_of :: (Integral a) => a -> [Integer]
powers_of n = sequence
where
    sequence = 1 : next sequence
    next (first : rest) = (n * first) : next rest
```

This gets me:

```
Could not deduce (a ~ Integer)
from the context (Integral a)
  bound by the type signature for
             powers_of :: Integral a => a -> [Integer]
  at Triangle.hs:(10,1)-(13,61)
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for powers_of :: Integral a => a -> [Integer]
      at Triangle.hs:10:1
Expected type: [Integer]
  Actual type: [a]
In the expression: sequence
In an equation for `powers_of':
    powers_of n
      = sequence
      where
          sequence = 1 : next sequence
          next (first : rest) = (n * first) : next rest
```

When I get rid of the `Integral` typeclass and make the signature just `Integer -> [Integer]`, everything is fine. Why is this? Is it some kind of failure of the type inference system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your type signature should be:

```
powers_of :: (Integral a) => a -> [a]
```

or

```
powers_of :: (Num a) => a -> [a]
```

The type of `1` is `Num a => a` and `(*)` is `Num a => a -> a -> a` so you can provide any `Num` instance and generate a list of that type.

There is no way to implicitly convert an instance of `Num` into an `Integer`. You could do so explicitly if required:

```
powers_of :: (Integral a) => a -> [Integer]
powers_of n = sequence
  where
    sequence = 1 : next sequence
    next (first : rest) = ((fromIntegral n) * first) : next rest
```

Answer (score 6):

It's absolutely not a failure of the inference system. It's a success of the inference system.

It observed `(*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`.  It observed that the first argument of `(*)` must unify with the argument to `powers_of`. It observed that the result of `(*)` must unify with the element type of the result list of `powers_of`.

These three things, taken together, say that the argument type of `powers_of` must be the same as the element type of the result list.

And the error message is telling you that it doesn't have any context to prove that `a` and `Integer` are the same type, which it needs for the function to type check.